# header location information cannot modify

Tags: php, header

```
<?php
 echo $_REQUEST['uname'];
 echo $_REQUEST['pass'];

$res= $mysql_query("select * from `sec` where uname='$_REQUEST['uname']' AND    `pass`='$_REQUEST['pass']'");

if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
{
 header('location:home.php')
}
else
{
 header('location:index.php')
}

?>
```

What's this error:`header  information cannot modify...`
even the username and passwords are correct it is not redirecting to another page and giving this warning..
why this error is coming??

Comment: Can't believe nobody's noted this one yet, but `$mysql_query`?  Really?  *Dollar*-mysql-query?  PHP should be throwing a *fit* at that.  Please make sure you have `error_reporting` turned all the way up.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you're passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input ($_REQUEST) *directly* into an SQL string! Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the php work should be done before sending any data to the browser.
If You are using your own code you should write code in this way

```
<?php 
include "action/home.php"; //don't echo anything here
include "view/home.php"; 
?>
```

OR

If you have to redirect after the header information have already been set, you should use javascript function to redirect as

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
{ ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.location="home.php";
  <script>
<?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a PHP header redirection after echoing data to the page.

Take the echoes out, and it should work. Also, put semicolons at the end of those header functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send headers after sending *any* output to the browser. You do that on your first two lines. You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

remove `echo` from first and second line of your code, don't put `echo` or `print_r` statement before `header('location:.....');`

Answer (score 1):

This error is mostly come when we use many time header location,
To avoid this error, you have to use another function instead of `header('location:home.php')`
Here is different function.

```
<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=home.php'>
```

Same for  `header('location:index.php')`
Replaced by `<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `header()` once something is outputted to the browser, you have echoed `$_REQUEST['uname'];` and `$_REQUEST['pass'];`, that's the reason why your code broke out.

You have two possible solution:
either remove those `echoes` or
use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)